# match position of all matched character in string with regexp in bash

Tags: regex, bash, hex, match

I'm trying to get all positions of specific characters matched via regexp. I can do this with *expr index* but this match only the first character in string.

```
echo $(expr index "$z" '[\x1F\x7F-\x9F]')
```

**note: $z is the var that contains the string**

This (correctly) returns:

```
6
```

I know that in this string i have two matched character at position 6 and 12 and i want returned all positions of matched chars, not only the first.

can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: I am pretty sure that `expr index` does not take a regex as its second argument, but I'd love to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a command using awk. It prints all the positions that match the regex `/0-9/`

```
echo $z | awk  '{s=$0; i=1; idx=0; 
       while(i>0){ 
           i=match(s, /[0-9]/); 
           if(i>0) {
                  idx += i;
                  print idx; 
                  s=substr(s, i+1);
           }
       }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You might like using `grep`.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

matches=();

# Used a "Process Substitution" because of the loop's subshell
while read match
do
    matches+=( "$match" );
done \
< <(
    printf '%s\n%s' \
        'somedata{a917am}some{8ka81a}data' \
        'awd123{ad123d}adad' \
        | grep -Eobn '\{[0-9a-z]{6}\}' # The magic is here
);

for (( i = 0; i < ${#matches[@]}; i++ ));
do
    matchRaw="${matches[$i]}";
    match="${matchRaw#*\:}";
    match="${match#*\:}";
    matchLine="${matchRaw%%\:*}";
    matchChar="${matchRaw#*\:}";
    matchChar="${matchChar%%\:*}";
    matchLength="${#match}";

    printf 'Match #%s, line %2s, char %2s, length %2s: "%s"\n' \
        "$((i + 1))" \
        "$matchLine" \
        "$matchChar" \
        "$matchLength" \
        "$match";
done
```

Outputs:

```js
Match #1, line  1, char  8, length  8: "{a917am}"
Match #2, line  1, char 20, length  8: "{8ka81a}"
Match #3, line  2, char 39, length  8: "{ad123d}"
```

Works on `grep (GNU grep) 2.25`.

Related:

```sh
grep --help

# -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
# -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
# -b, --byte-offset         print the byte offset with output lines
# -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
```

[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution) ([from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691677/5113030))