# Where the value of the counter variable was? linux -bash

Tags: linux, bash, email

I wanted to know where it is changing the counter variable, I use it to count mail addresses contained in a file, when I print out the cycle, the value disappears from the terminal, on the other hand if the print within the cycle, the value is correct. So I do not understand where the value is lost, and I must print out the cycle as it is right

```
    cat $FILENAME_2 | while read LINE
 do
   if [ "$LINE" = "" ]
   then
    echo "blanks"
    exit 1
  fi 
  TEST=${LINE:0:1}
//verify string start with  #    
  if [  "$TEST" != "#"  ] ; then
  let CONTADOR=CONTADOR+1 
  cat html_list | mail -a "Content-type:text/html" -s "$ASUNTO" $LINE
  echo "Mail enviado a $LINE"
   fi   
echo "i send $CONTADOR mails" //print mails count
 done
echo "i send $CONTADOR mails" // print blank space
```

Comment: I cannot see the scope of the variable. Can you paste the whole code? Otherwise, check to see if $CONTADOR is declared inside an area that is not accessible after the done command.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/rq13yRpT

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add element to array in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691436/unable-to-add-element-to-array-in-bash). While this is not the only, and not necessarily the best duplicate, the problem is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan is a same problem , but these ask title, no resolved my problem , so I ask here ! 
Sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the variable is lost because when you use `|` you fork a new subshell. The variable `CONTADOR` is created in the sub-shell. When you come out of it (i.e after `done`) that variable holds no value.

The right way to read a file is

```
while read LINE; do  
  # do stuff here 
done < "$FILENAME_2"
```

Read more about using a `while loop` for reading data at [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: Thans JayPal , It worked perfectly, I did not know what the | running on another terminal

thanks for links,