# Only the first values gets appended to the array

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, shell

I have this piece of code inside a bash script. It asks the user if the file we generated has to be send to the standardTo (emails which the file is generally send to), or if the user on this occasion wants to send to different mails. If yes emailsTo=standardTo. If no, it doesn't use standardTo, it asks for the mails, checks if these are actual mails and than adds them to emailsTo. Now the problem is that only the first value gets appended to the array.

The syntax for doing this found on similar topics is always the same and looks clear to me: array+=(new value). So that is what I am doing.

I also read this :
[Unable to add element to array in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691436/unable-to-add-element-to-array-in-bash)
and think that maybe my second 'case $yn' is creating the 'subshell behaviour', but I don't really understand how that would work than and how I can make sure this behaviour doesn't happen.

How do I make sure also the second, third, .. values also get appended to the array?

```bash
#!/bin/bash
standardTo=("blabla@hotmail.com" "blabloe@hotmail.com")

while true; do
    echo standard users are: "${standardTo[@]}"
    read -p "Do you wish to send to standard users ? " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) emailsTo=${standardTo[*]}
            break;;
        [Nn]* )
            regex="^[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+\$"
            addmails=
            #declare –a
            emailsTo=()
            while [[ ! $addmails ]]; do
                #ask user for input
                read -p "Enter email : " email
                if [[ $email =~ $regex ]]; then
                    echo "$email is valid"
                    emailsTo+=("$email")
                    read -p "Do you wish to add another mail ? " yn
                    case $yn in
                        [Yy]* ) addmails=;;
                        [Nn]* ) addmails=false;;
                    esac
                else
                    echo "$email is invalid"
                    addmails=
                fi
            done
            break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

echo "loop printing all values in emailsto:"

for mail in $emailsTo
do
echo $mail
done


#setup mailstring to --> this does work 
mailtostring=""
for mail in $emailsTo
do 
    mailtostring="$mail, $mailtostring"
done
```

screenshot of the program:

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear. You assign once to `standardTo`, but never modify it later, so I guess that you are refering to the array `emailsTo`. In the very least, print the result of `emailsTo` in the end, and post a transscript from a session where we can see the dialogue, and what the user enters on response of the `read` statements.

Comment: You are correct is misexplained what was happening. I re-explained. emailsTo prints the first value that is being appended.

Comment: I neither see in your post a statement which would print the array `emailsTo`, nor do I see a screenshot of a transscript of running the program....

Comment: Well I wrote a for loop for you printing them out. It is easily reproducible. Though I ran it for you in took a screenshot, showing you that I am not lying. The relevant part for you starts on line 6 of the screenshot: "standard users are: "

Comment: Ah, now I see it. The loop looks wrong to me. Do a `for mail in "${emailsTo[@]}"`.

Comment: Okay, you are correct, but why in this case does it needs the array to be set like that? I'm not an expert but I looped to many variables doing it the way I previously did and it worked. Moreover, later in the program the mailing gets executed with a loop working like how I just echo'd it and it also worked.

Comment: `emailsTo=("${standardTo[@]}")`

Comment: _"later in the program the mailing gets executed with a loop working like how I just echo'd it and it also worked"_ - then, later in the program, you did something differently. My _guess_ is that you looped over a scalar instead of over an array - but since you haven't shown what you've done later in the program, it's hard nail it down exactly.

Comment: As the [tag:bash] tag you use instructs - "For shell scripts with syntax or other errors, please check them at https://shellcheck.net before posting them here.".

Comment: I've added the other loop that works perfectly.

Comment: anyway thanks for the people answering and not downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

First, thank you for providing enough context to answer the problem! But I suspect you'd've found the answer yourself if you looked for the [smallest, self-contained, complete example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions), which would be something like this:

```bash
$ a=(one two three)  # Initialize an array.
$ echo "$a"          # "$a" expands to the first element only.
one
$ echo "${a[@]}"     # This expands to all elements.
one two three
```

From this, you'll find the problem in the example code:

```bash
for mail in $emailsTo   # Should be "${emailsTo[@]}".
do
echo $mail
done

#setup mailstring to --> this does work 
mailtostring=""
for mail in $emailsTo    # Should be "${emailsTo[@]}".
do 
    mailtostring="$mail, $mailtostring"
done
```

---

A second problem is that `emailsTo` is declared as a simple variable here:

```bash
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) emailsTo=${standardTo[*]}
```

But it's treated as an array variable here:

```bash
                   emailsTo+=("$email")
```

In general, the best practice is to:

1. Use double-quotes and braces in variable expansions, unless there's a reason not to. That avoids problems in expansions like
   `x="a ${var}iable expansion"`
2. Treat a variable that contains individual items as an array.
3. Expand array variables as `"${a[@]}"` rather than `${a[*]}` if you want to treat each item as an individual word, even if it contains spaces.
4. Use `$IFS` to change the separator between elements when you expand the variable.

Putting that all together:

```bash
$ emailsTo=("${standardTo[@]}")  # Create an array.
$ emailsTo+=("${email}")         # Add an element.

$ echo "${emailsTo[@]}"
me@here you@there them@anywhere  # Example output.
```

Finally, if you want a comma-separated string, you can set `$IFS` to a comma, expand the array with `"${emailsTo[*]}"` (quoted, expanded with `*`), and then reset `$IFS`:

```bash
$ ifs="$IFS"; IFS=","; echo "${emailsTo[*]}"; IFS="${ifs}"
me@here,you@there,them@anywhere
```